# template T4 type xdocument not defined

Tags: vb.net, templates

I got this error when i execute my template T4:
 "type xdocument  not defined" !!!

And this the Code of my T4:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="VB" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Linq.XDocument" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>


<# dim xx as new XDocument#>
```

Comment: wich one? XDocument??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imported `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`.

XDocument here is the class, so you only want to import the namespace its in, not the class itself, so just import `System.Xml.Linq`.

Also, you need to include a reference to `System.Xml.Linq`. In the case of templates this is done using the `assembly` statement (like the one you already have for `System.Core`).

So you need to include this at the top:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.Linq" #>
```

(Including System.Xml is to be on the safe side - you'll probably use something from that library as well at some point).

Comment: already done. I also tried with xmlDocument, but still have the some problem